# How to toggle audio between PC and TV set?

Tags: shell-script, pulseaudio, kubuntu, hdmi

I created a script that toggles audio output between PC and TV set connected via HDMI. It looks so:

```
inactive_sink_id=$(pacmd list-sinks | grep -E "[^*] index: [0-9]+" | sed -r -e "s/.*([0-9]+)/\1/g")

pacmd set-default-sink $inactive_sink_id

move_sink_to_id=$(pacmd list-sink-inputs | grep -E "index: [0-9]+" | sed -r -e "s/.* ([0-9]+)/\1/g")

pacmd move-sink-input $move_sink_to_id $inactive_sink_id
```

But sometimes it works, sometimes doesn't.

For example, it happened so that a youtube video was playing, I could hear the sound on my PC. After I had switched to another position in video no sound could be heard. I opened "Audio and Video Settings" and noticed that TV set HDMI was at the top of "Device Preference" list.

What is a reliable way to toggle audio output?

I've noticed that although my script does some changes, the "Audio and Video Settings" remain unchanged:

```
$ pacmd list-sinks | grep index
  * index: 0
    index: 1

$ toggle-audio-between-pc-and-tv.sh   # My script

$ pacmd list-sinks | grep index
    index: 0
  * index: 1
```

[image]
Turn on the TV set

Play a video. No sound.

However when I execute my script multiple times the sound is switched to TV set.

It seems that `pacmd` actions and "Audio and Video Settings" dialog aren't in sync.

Comment: Not sure what exactly happened in your case, but `module-stream-restore` may also set the sink of a newly started application to the last sink it uses. Another possible influence are the "roles", but these are usually only used for embedded systems. None of this may help if you are seeing another effect, though. Try to reliably reproduce the effect, then you can go looking for the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Concluding from you variable names, you don't understand what's going on here.

This line is fine. (But not if you have more than two sinks.) You're looking for the sink without `*` and assigning it to `inactive_sink_id`.

```
inactive_sink_id=$(pacmd list-sinks | grep -E "[^*] index: [0-9]+" | sed -r -e "s/.*([0-9]+)/\1/g")
```

This one's fine too. As long as you only have two sinks. If you have more, there will be an error as the variable will contain many numbers.

```
pacmd set-default-sink $inactive_sink_id
```

This one might also be fine, but with one input only. And the variable name here is not fine.

```
move_sink_to_id=$(pacmd list-sink-inputs | grep -E "index: [0-9]+" | sed -r -e "s/.* ([0-9]+)/\1/g")
```

You're not moving a sink to an id. You're moving an input to a sink identified by an id. (The ids don't change. Why would they?) If there are more inputs, this line will not work, as the `move_sink_to_id` will contain many integers:

```
pacmd move-sink-input $move_sink_to_id $inactive_sink_id
```

Try to use this construct:

```
for input in $(pactl list short sink-inputs | awk '{print $1}'); do
    pacmd move-sink-input $input $inactive_sink_id
done
```

Now you're sure that every input is moved to the target sink. This is important, because even if you pause one YouTube video, it still lingers on the input list for some time. You can do some experiments with

```
pactl list short sink-inputs
```

and see how PulseAudio sees it.

Also, I'd change the name `inactive_sink_id` to `target_sink_id` and would introduce a coverage for the situation when there are more than two sinks. This might be a hard coding based on the sink name. You can refer to sinks not only by id, but also by name, eg.

```
pactl move-sink-input 65 alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
```

Or you may introduce a possibly optional select list that will let you choose where you want to move the inputs.

This command produces a clear list of sinks with names in the second column:

```
pactl list short sinks
```

**And make sure you run your script no sooner than PulseAudio can see your TV sink!**

The final script might look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

target_sink=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo

pactl list short sinks | grep -- "$target_sink" || {
    echo Sink "$target_sink" not found! >&2
    exit 1
}
pacmd set-default-sink "$target_sink"
for input in $(pactl list short sink-inputs | awk '{print $1}'); do
    pacmd move-sink-input "$input" "$target_sink"
done
```

Comment: There are only 2 sinks by me. I want to toggle audio output between the PC and the TV set after every script execution. So "target_sink" will always be different.

Comment: Then you might define both of them and determine the target as not the current default, eg. using `pactl info | grep 'Default Sink' | awk '{print $3}'`. This would keep you prepared for any new ones.

Comment: The problem is I don't see what your script does functionally differently than mine and how it solves the issue I described...

Comment: @ka3ak The difference is that it moves ALL inputs.